# For every 3-regular graph $G$ there exists a 3-regular planar graph $G'$ such that $C(G) = C(G')$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

$C(G)$ denotes the cycle set of $G$ (the set of lengths of all cycles of $G$). This question came up recently and I have been meaning to take a stab at it, but I wanted to know if there exists some well known counterexample. Even dropping 3-regularity, the statement is not at all trivial. For example, thinking that one could simply construct such a graph $G'$ by

$$
G' = \bigoplus_{n \in C(G)} \mathcal{C}_n
$$

Where $\mathcal{C}_n$ denotes the cycle graph on $n$ vertices is simply wrong, since this construction introduces more cycles in $G'$ that are not in $G$. What is perhaps more interesting, is that this statement seems to imply the Erdős–Gyárfás conjecture, if paired with the main result of [this](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p7) paper. Could this ever possibly be true?

Comment: If what you mean by "cycle set" is the set of all *lengths* of cycles in $G$, which would explain the "$n \in C(G)$" in your notation, then I also have an answer. But I would like clarification on this first, since this is unusual terminology.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I thought it was standard notation, I am sorry.

Comment: It might be standard notation for people who think about cycle length problems like the Erdős–Gyárfás conjecture a lot! My default assumption was that you take the set of all cycles, because that's also a common thing to look at. Anyway, now I know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Heawood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph) is a counterexample.

[image]

It is a $3$-regular graph with girth $6$; the set of cycle lengths in the graph is $\{6, 8, 10, 12, 14\}$.

A $3$-regular planar graph cannot have girth $6$. This is a bound via Euler's formula: in general, if the girth of an $n$-vertex planar graph is $k$, [it has at most $\frac{k}{k-2}(n-2)$ edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075486/383078), which is at most $\frac64(n-2) = \frac32n - 3$ edges in our case. But a $3$-regular $n$-vertex graph must have exactly $\frac32n$ edges.